# What is the reading of 弓形?

Tags: readings, wago-and-kango, multiple-readings

The word 弓形 has three different readings which are きゅうけい, ゆみがた, and ゆみなり.  Unfortunately, there does not seem to be much distinction between these three readings. Is this simply a case wherein all readings are acceptable or is one reading more common than the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kun-reading ゆみがた is the safest reading at least in ordinary speech and writings.

弓形 may be read きゅうけい in some technical fields I'm not good at, but I can say it's rare. In mathematical contexts, this word is normally called ゆみがた (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mrc_QlL_nc&feature=youtu.be&t=120) and this [Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BC%93%E5%BD%A2) for example), not きゅうけい. I guess this is because there is a more common word with the same reading, 球形 ("spherical").

ゆみなり is a common word, but it's usually written as 弓なり in modern Japanese.